# Can rand() really be this bad?

Tags: c++, macos, random

[image: lol]

Above is an example image generated by using rand() to get random coordinates and add a constant to the pixel value at those coordinates. This is how it looks from a few thousand iterations. I'm using the rand() from stdlib.h in Mac OS X Lion, giving it time(NULL) as the seed.

You can clearly see the vertical lines, as if the ones with an odd x-coordinate have higher values than those with even x-coordinates.

How would I implement a better algorithm, or where can I find one that doesn't have many dependencies? (I would prefer a header-only file).

Here's the code (sorry it took me so long):

```
void generate(int iterations = 1) {
 for (unsigned int x = 0;x < (area * 4);++x) {
  map[rand() % area] += 1;
 }
 number a = min();
 number b = max();
 for (int i = 0;i < area;++i) {
  map[i] -= a;
  map[i] /= b;
 }
}
```

Map contains double-floats and is later turned into RGB values.

Comment: Are you 100% certain we can't exclude a bug in your use of `rand()`?

Comment: How are you constraining the rand() value to your valid range?  Are you mod'ing (%'ing) it with the range or doing something else?

Comment: Please post code that shows how you used `rand()`.

Comment: Yes, `rand()` is pretty horrible. In most implementations it's just a simple LCG and unsuitable for anything beyond rolling a die maybe (and even then most programmers do stupid things, e.g. `rand() % 6 + 1`).

Comment: Code or it didn't happen.

Comment: The behavior looks like some precision is being lost (round off with % perhaps)

Comment: Lets see the code. For all we know you could using it incorrectly. 1) Do you call srand() more than once. When calling rand() how do you truncate to X/Y coordinates.

Comment: Instead of `map[rand() % area] += 1;`, use `map[rand() / (((unsigned) RAND_MAX + 1) / area)] += 1;`.  This is an improvement because the higher bits from `rand()` have a better distribution than the lower bits, assuming it's an LGC.

Comment: @DietrichEpp thanks, but there isn't much of a difference. I tried arc4random and it works better but you still see those vertical lines. I'll have a look at the C++11 stuff soon.

Comment: For posterity, adding a link to this answer that pretty much explains it - http://stackoverflow.com/a/20267526/2016408

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [`arc4random()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man3/arc4random.3.html)? It provides much stronger and more uniform random values than `rand()`.

You could also try [`SecRandomCopyBytes()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Security/Reference/RandomizationReference/Reference/reference.html), which is part of Security.framework. This basically just reads from /dev/random.

Answer (score 4):

C++11 provides pretty useful random number functionality in [random](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Move_semantics#Extensible_random_number_facility). See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) and [here](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#std-random) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

I think it would be most important to see how you use `rand()` to extract the coordinates. What is really surprising is, that you only see a pattern in the x coordinates, but not in the y ones. If there really was a deficiency in `rand()` it should appear in both.

That said, I could attempt a guess where these patterns come from: `rand()` is well known to produce more randomness in the high bits than in the low ones. Hence one should never use modulo to extract a smaller range, because this way one will only get the low bit parts with less randomness.

From this knowledge I would guess that you were extracting the low bits to produce the x values and the high bits to extract the y values. This would give you a much more random pattern along the y axis than along the x axis.

If this is now what you are doing, there still must be some artifact in your code, which causes larger randomness across the y axis than along the x axis. So without seeing your code it is hard to tell if this implementation is flawed.

Answer (score 1):

On the mac you can just use random instead of rand. The man page for `random` notes the following:

> **BUGS**
>
> About 2/3 the speed of rand(3).
>
> The historical implementation used to have a very weak seeding; the random sequence did not vary much with the seed.  The current implementation employs a better pseudo-random number generator for the initial state calculation.
>
> Applications requiring cryptographic quality randomness should use arc4random(3).