# Rand() % 14 only generates the values 6 or 13

Tags: c++, random, srand

Whenever I run the following program the returned values are always 6 or 13.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

//void randomLegs();
//void randomPush();
//void randomPull();
//void randomMisc();


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    //randomLegs();
    cout << rand() % 14;
    return 0;
}
```

I have run the program close to a hundred times during today and yesterday.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you.

EDIT: By the way, if I change the range of rand() to say 13 or 15 it works just fine.

Comment: If you have specific requirements beyond those `rand` is guarantted to meet, don't use `rand`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can reproduce the problem on Mac OS X 10.9 with Xcode 5 - it looks like it might actually be a bug, or at least a limitation with `rand()`/`srand()` on OS X 10.9.

I recommend you use [arc4random()](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random.3.html) instead, which works a lot better than `rand()`, and which doesn't require that you randomize the seed:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    cout << (arc4random() % 14) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Test:

```
$ g++ -Wall -O3 srand.cpp && ./a.out
5
$ ./a.out
8
$ ./a.out
0
$ ./a.out
8
$ ./a.out
11
$ ./a.out
8
$ ./a.out
3
$ ./a.out
13
$ ./a.out
9
$
```

Comment: Thank you Paul. This solution is simple and it solves my problem.

Comment: Why use another library, if the Standard library has alternatives too? See `<random>`, in particular `std::mt19937` which is a known-good RNG. It also comes with `std::uniform_int_distribution`

Comment: @MSalters: `arc4random()` is pretty standard on Mac OS X, iOS, and various BSD platforms, and doesn't require an additional library.

Comment: @MSalters `arc4random()` is in the BSD C library, it doesn't require any additional setup. Also, not everyone can use or assume the availability of C++11 for various reasons.

Comment: @PaulR Exactly. Also, an even better solution would be to use `arc4random_uniform(MAX)` instead of `arc4random() % MAX`.

Answer (score 42):

Per [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator), the multiplier being used in Apple's MCG random number generator is 16807. This is divisible by 7, so the first random number produced after `srand()` will have only one bit of entropy `mod 14` (that is, it can only take on two values).

It's a crappy RNG they've got there. An easy solution, though, is just to call `rand()` a few times right after `srand`, and discard the results.

Comment: +1, beautiful explanation! I wasn't aware how flaky these things could be. Usually the explanation I see for "why you should never modulo over a short range" is just that it's not uniform around the edges.

Comment: Incidentally, an even simpler workaround is to wait about 18 million years, and then try the program again. At that point, the value returned by `time()` will be great enough to push the entropy "around the corner" into the low-order bits. Give that a try, and let our descendants know how it works out. :-D

Comment: That's why [`rand() % 7` always return 0](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7866754/995714)

Answer (score 3):

`rand() % 14` is often a poor random number generator. You'll probably get better results with this

```
(int)(14*(rand()/(RAND_MAX + 1.0)))
```

Comment: This is the only non-deleted answer left!  Hang in there @john!

Comment: Just to clarify. I'm not the one deleting answers.

Comment: @user3045273, don't worry - they were deleted by their owners.

Comment: If the answer given by Sneftel is correct, then this would be a valid solution. I want my downvote back!

Comment: This actually isn't better. It just produces a different unequally weighted distribution. Pretend that `rand()` generates values from 0 to 9, inclusive. If you distribute those values into 9 buckets, at least one bucket will get 2 or more values, regardless of how you decide to distribute the values. The solution is to **discard** some values, so that the number of generated values is a multiple of the number of buckets. For this case, find the largest multiple of 14 that's less than or equal to RAND_MAX, and whenever `rand()` generates a value that's larger than that multiple, try again.

Comment: John's solution produces a value with about 3.8 bits of entropy, versus the original code which produced 1 (and extremely close to the theoretical maximum). So yes, it actually is better.