# ANSI C / rand() % 7 first value is always 3

Tags: c, random, modulus, srand

So trying to figure out what is special about rand() mod k7 in C. In another post someone said that C rand() uses http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator but I don't see what makes (mod k7) k-> scalar special for the algorithm associated to ANSI C.

So I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void getRand(int* num1, int* num2, int* num3);


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

        srand(time(NULL));
        printf("%d\n", rand() % 7 );

        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This always prints 3. But if I use any n such that 7 does not divide n, I get a better sequence of first values. Still obviously not random but better then just 3 or some c mod 7 = 3.

I deliberately made the program this way with the seed in the loop to show that the first value always returns 3 regardless of the seed.

Yes I could get random numbers for `Xn n > 0` but I want `X1 % 7 != X1 % 7` for each Xo.

Comment: Set the seed to time only once

Comment: You should be calling `srand()` only once.

Comment: Even with the reseed, it still prints a bunch of 3's. I would expect the rand() start value to change every second given time() changes every second, yet it seems not to.  srand() apparently isn't that granular.

Comment: Where in your posted code are you actually changing the seed?  Why don't you post the actual code you are running as the illustrative code, not the code you are not running.

Comment: @RobertHarvey He's changing the seed via `time()` with sleeps. It wasn't obvious at all how they were related. My initial throught was 100 iterations is all gonna complete in under one second so the `time()` will all return the same number.

Comment: @Mysticial: That would be my guess as well.

Comment: I get the following sequence of output using gcc 4.8.2: `6 1 3 6 3 5 1 5 0 2`. I changed the loop to compute only 10 times.

Comment: I read this, then the meta, then this, then the meta, and _THEN_ I understood the question.  I think.  The question is why rand()%7 always returns 3 even when seeded with 100 unique times.  This question is _very_ unclear.  Especially since there's several abbreviations and notations unfamiliar to me: "` if I use any n s.t. !(7|n),`"

Comment: @RobertHarvey that is the code, and as Mysticial said I am using a bit of an unorthodox method such as sleep but I wanted it so I could see it occur in a loop rather then have to run the program 100+ times myself, I can edit it with output if you like with various modulus entries, but I felt that if someone was really able to answer this they would copy and paste and tinker with it themselves

Comment: @RSahu so may be a compiler thing

Comment: What would be more useful is if you could confirm, on your own hardware, that `time(NULL)` is actually returning *different* values in the loop.

Comment: @MooingDuck 7|n means 7 divides n so !(7|n) would mean 7 does not divide n

Comment: I think what he means is that it is not immediately clear what `n s.t.` means.  Is it the number `n`, *such that?*

Comment: @RobertHarvey I assumed it was because again if I use mod 6 lets say I get a X1 = range(1-5)

Comment: @RobertHarvey aye yea sorry

Comment: Does `time(NULL)` return different values each time through the loop?

Comment: @ThomasWatters It is most likely a platform/compiler issue. What platform/compiler are you using?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I also didn't understand `!(7|n)`.  I'd probably write that as `n%7 != 0`

Comment: @R Sahu it was ran on XCode which I understand to be compiling with GCC but not sure which version

Comment: @RSahu i don't think you answered my original question but at least now I know that somehow its related to the compiler. I wasn't sure if 7 was just some magic number for the algorithm being used and if so someone with the background may be able to answer why 7 was magic in whatever pseodrandom hash was being used.

Comment: Are you, perchance, using Mac OS X 10.9 with Xcode 5?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20263187/rand-14-only-generates-the-values-6-or-13

Comment: @MooingDuck OS X 10.8.5 with Xcode 5

Comment: @MooingDuck lol so looks like you found the almost duplicate post. Same issue it seems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, lets start with looking at more than just a few data points:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    size_t counters[7] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    time_t tt = time(NULL);

    //for (size_t i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    //  printf("result: %d count: %d\n", i, counters[i]);
    //}

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        srand(tt + i);
        counters[rand() % 7] ++;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        printf("result: %d count: %d\n", i, counters[i]);
    }
}
```

with this, on Windows 7, Visual Studio 2013 compile as C++ I get

```
result: 0 count: 142894
result: 1 count: 142850
result: 2 count: 142848
result: 3 count: 142855
result: 4 count: 142854
result: 5 count: 142845
result: 6 count: 142854
```

what do you get, because I suspect you'll get a better result from a larger data set.

Comment: Of course, what you're really showing is that this doesn't affect Visual C++'s runtime library.  (Based on use of `unistd.h` in the question, I'm almost positive it isn't tested on Windows)

Comment: @BenVoigt  Yes, I get that also... but my two questions are "so you %7 a rand and get 3 after seeding, SO WHAT?" and "what happens when you test a larger data set" so here's my larger data set code for OP to test.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim first off appreciate you trying to figure this one out for me. Heres my output:    code' result: 0 count: 127773
result: 1 count: 127773
result: 2 count: 172736
result: 3 count: 188398
result: 4 count: 127774
result: 5 count: 127773
result: 6 count: 127773

Comment: "Per wikipedia, the multiplier being used in Apple's MCG random number generator is 16807. This is divisible by 7, so the first random number produced after srand() will have only one bit of entropy mod 14 (that is, it can only take on two values)." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20263187/rand-14-only-generates-the-values-6-or-13

Comment: So why is it so heavy on 2 and 3

Comment: @MooingDuck what does it mean to have one bit of entropy mod 14?

Comment: @Thomas so when you run longer you get a more random distribution. Makes me think your see the effects and small change in you seed numbers.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim yes "more" random but still 2 and 3 seem to have a skewed weight in comparison dont you think?

Comment: @thomas. Yes and no. It's a approximation of randomness and as Mooing Duck points out if the modulo used has a 7 as the last digit that explains a lot. So why does this matter? And why are you hung up on %7 the rand results. What are you really trying to here that this is impacting. Or are you nearly point outing that a rand is not crypto safe?

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim no no nothing that advance, my buddy has some CS I project "simulating" a slot machine and he asked me why he kept getting a 4 for the first number, he was using rand() % 7 + 1; I was stumped

Comment: Maybe then seed once and take and throw away the first 10 results.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim: or use a different engine, arc4random seems to be what other XCoders are recommending as a workaround.  I'm not sure how many results you'd have to discard before subsequent results get 4 bits of entropy.  It's even possible that it never happens.

Comment: @MooingDuck agreed, but if it a CS program and their slot machine spins a 4 on the first spin. It's not a big issue. Unless they are being tested on real world gaming machine payout behavior regulations adherence.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim: Actually, his prior tests seem to show that it doesn't fully get enough bits ever, since he gets 3 on 18.84% of attempts instead of the expected 14.29%.  For homework it's probably fine though

Comment: @MooingDuck I'd say it's fit for purpose for must games. Or projects where you just don't want 100 results that are all the same. The mention of entropy get very close to crypto talk at which point it's super not suitable.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim so decided to go back and look at this same problem today and now instead of printing 3 each time it only prints 1, weird stuff

Comment: @Thomas no not wired at all do a hundered thousand seed operations and then take first and see a distribution. Yes the first number is correlated  to the date, but this rand is not very good. You really need to understand that. But as long as you only seed it once per execution of you program. It will mostly appear random.