# arc4Random() - generate numbers "jumping after 10"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, random, arc4random

I'm not sure how to format `arc4Random()` to generate random numbers between 200 and 300. I would like numbers like 200, 210, 220 and so on.. (not 200, 201, 202, ...)
(Xcode 5.1.1, iOS)

Any idea?

My piece of code:

```
self.currentObstacX += arc4random()%(200+10) + 300;
```

... but it looks like it does not work how I need.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@PaulR answer will work but it is better to use `arc4random_uniform` like this...

```
NSInteger number = 10 * arc4random_uniform(11) + 200;
```

From the docs...

> arc4random_uniform() is recommended over constructions like
>   ``arc4random() % upper_bound'' as it avoids
>        "modulo bias" when the upper bound is not a power of two.

Comment: @PaulR it was pointed out to me on SO a while ago and I've stuck by it ever since :D Easier to read as well I think.

Comment: Evidently I'm a slow learner as this same thing was pointed out to me some time ago also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20267313/253056 (see bottom comment) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int x = 10 * (arc4random() % 11) + 200; // x = 10 * (0..10) + 200
```