# Why do I get nearly the same number out of the rand() function in the first iteration?

Tags: c, random, iteration, clion, srand

in my C99-programme I want to use pseudo-random numbers between 0 an 1.
Unfortunatly, my programme always generates a first number that is almost identical. It just steps up ever so slightly every time I rerun my programme.

This is the relevant part of my programme:

```
srand(time(NULL));  
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    float a = (float)rand()/RAND_MAX;
    printf("%f\n",a);
```

And here are the results of two Iterations with a time difference of below 10 seconds:

```
0.717103
0.357464
0.903628
0.271930
0.327478
0.917489
0.231215
0.026307
0.135259
0.290941

0.717221
0.330531
0.237708
0.151682
0.318986
0.201876
0.936884
0.209277
0.324705
0.311334
```

I tried to generate completely different numbers no matter how many I computed before, but the first is alway close to the same.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: This might help: [first rand() generates the same value after srand(time(0))](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27301090/13843268).

Comment: `srand(time(NULL));` should not be there. Call it once only at the beginning of `main`.

Comment: @WeatherVane: That is not the problem here.

Comment: @sj95126: That is not the issue here.

Answer (score 2):

Patterns like this are typically caused by low-quality [linear congruential pseudorandom number generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator). Each random number is computed as *X*<sub>new</sub> = (*aX*<sub>old</sub> + *c*) mod *m*. When you seed this with a number of seconds, the change between the first value generated after seeding at one time and the first value generated after seeding one second later is *a* modulo *m*.

If you are using a Unix system (such as macOS or Linux), you can use [`srandom`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/srandom.html) and [`random`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/random.html) instead.

Answer (score 2):

The problem appears to be that your system's `rand()` implementation is sensitive to the fact that successive return values from `time()` don't differ by much — that is, aren't supplying much entropy.

I tried your code on my machine and got remarkably similar results.

You need to provide a bit more entropy, to "mix things up".

One technique I like to use (at least, on Unix-like systems) is to add the process ID into the seed, since the pid will be different each time.  Usually I've done it like this:

```
srand(time(NULL) + getpid());
```

This is a good way to make sure your program generates different results even if you invoke it twice in the same second.

Unfortunately, this wasn't enough to make a difference with your code on my machine, and I suspect it won't help on yours, either.  The problem is that (especially on a non-loaded system) the process ID typically just increments by 1 or 2 each time also, and it's adding in to the same low-order bits of `time`'s return value which also aren't changing by much.  (And the *high* order bits of the pid don't change at all, and are being added to the high-order bits of the time of day, which also aren't changing.)

On my system, I got decent results with

```
srand(time(NULL) ^ (getpid() << 16));
```

and I suggest you try this.

If that doesn't help, you'll want to use either a significantly better entropy source, or a significantly better pseudorandom number generator.

These days, virtually all Unix-like systems have a good source of entropy accessible via the special file `/dev/random`.  So a superior way of seeding a pseudorandom number generator is with code like this:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("/dev/random", "rb");
if(fp != NULL) {
    unsigned int seed;
    fread(&seed, sizeof(seed), 1, fp);
    srand(seed);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

(For a production program, obviously you'd have to decide what to do if the `fopen` call failed.)

[Eric Postpischil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74668873/why-do-i-get-nearly-the-same-number-out-of-the-rand-function-in-the-first-iter/74669203#74669203) mentions `random`, a significantly better PRNG available on most systems.