# clang - poor rand() implementation

Tags: c, gcc, random, numbers, clang

I had made a [Pong](https://github.com/Aniruddha-Deb/Pong) game where I had to randomize the throw of the ball. To do this, I used the inbuilt random number generator and got good results in Ubuntu/GCC. On porting the code to Mac and compiling, the ball would only be projected in a single direction, meaning that the `rand()` function in clang was not working as expected.

I have since reverted to a custom number generator, but here's the original problematic code in the game:

```c
srand(time(NULL));
float ang = ((float)rand())/RAND_MAX * 120 - 60;
int side = (int)(((float)rand())/RAND_MAX * 2);
```

Upon further inspection, I created the following test program and compiled and ran it on both platforms.

```c
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    while (1) {
        int now = time(NULL);
        printf("Time now is %d\n", now);
        srand(now);
        int random = rand();
        printf("Random number generated is %d\n", random);
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

The results (tabulated and calculated against `RAND_MAX`, which is `2147483647` on both systems) are as follows:

[image]

The results speak for themselves. While there is randomness in the clang version, as compared to the value of `RAND_MAX`, the randomness is very poor and is evidenced by the standard deviation of 0, compared to the standard deviation of 0.328 on gcc.

**What are the reason(s) for this poor behaviour of `rand()` on clang**? I would also like to see the reference implementation of this function in the header file. This seems nonstandard, and I must not be the only one who ran into problems while porting programs using this method to Mac. What other design principles are good practice while using/relying upon random number generators?

Comment: According to Mac themselves, their implementation of `rand()` is bad: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/srand.3.html ... and obsoleted by `random()`

Comment: I'd love to see the source code of this srand() and rand() implementation.

Comment: I'd say the most important principle is to choose a random number generator that has stood up to analysis and is still respected today. The only thing that `rand()` has going for it is portability. Note that there is no requirement that `rand()` be poorly implemented, it just seems that it often is.

Comment: What happens if you call `rand()` multiple times after calling `srand()`? Does it still vary only slightly?

Comment: Don't blame clang or praise gcc; the random number generator is part of the system standard library, not the compiler.  Rather, it's MacOS vs glibc.

Comment: [srand() — why call it only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7343833/995714)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Reason it was Not Behaving Right:

So I don't know the exact implementation for apple's clang implementation for rand, however I know it was done as a LCG, or Linear Congruential Generator. The way it works is basically a formula:

[image]

In the formula, [image] would be the `RAND_MAX`, [image] and [image] are some constant defined by the compiler. Apple's Clang used `16807` and `0` respectably.

The return for `rand()` is [image], and last return of `rand()` or the value you put in `srand()` would be [image].

If you just want a sequence of number, that are kinda random, this works pretty well, as it would eventually return all numbers between `0` and `RAND_MAX`, without a noticeable pattern by human.

However, with some calculations, you can easily spot it would have some problem if you just put a continuous sequence of number in the place of [image] in that formula (which is what you did). The difference between each call of `rand()` would be exactly equals to [image], except when [image] is actually close to `RAND_MAX`.

---

### Correct Way of Using it:

The correct ways of getting random number through `rand()` function is only calling `srand()` once at the beginning, and use only `rand()` in the loop.

Alternatively, there are many other random generating formula you could look for, and you can probably find some here: [How to generate a random int in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822323/how-to-generate-a-random-int-in-c)

Comment: this is the result of the trashy `rand()`: [Why does rand() % 7 always return 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7866754/995714), [Rand() % 14 only generates the values 6 or 13](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20263187/995714)